# Exclude a folder inside temp when executing a del batch file

Tags: batch-file, cmd

What do I add to my DEL batch file if I want to exclude a folder inside a folder I want to delete?

I have this code to delete my all the contents of the temp folder

```
DEL /F /Q C:\temp
```

Now, I want to exclude a folder named ***imptfolder*** inside. This shouldn't be deleted whether it exists or not inside the temp folder. How do I do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's some batch script code that'll do what you're asking.

```
for /d %%I in (c:\temp\*) do (
    if /i not "%%~nxI" equ "imptfolder" rmdir /q /s "%%~I"
)
del /q c:\temp\*
```

If you're just entering these commands from the console, use single percents rather than double.

```
cd /d c:\temp
for /d %I in (*) do @(if /i not "%~I" equ "imptfolder" rmdir /q /s "%~I")
del /q *
```

Comment: Is there a way to do multiple folders with this script?

Comment: Yeah, `for /d` works pretty similarly to a plain `for` loop.  Try `for /d %%I in (c:\folder1\* c:\folder2\* "c:\folder with spaces\*") do...`