# Batch file to delete folder but leave a certain subfolder?

Tags: batch-file, file-io

I'm trying to clear a folder of all it's contents but a certain sub-folder and its contents. My deleting works fine but I can't figure out how to exclude.

```
cd C:\testfolder
del * /S /Q
rmdire /S /Q "C:\testfolder"
```

But I do not want to delete the folder `C:\testfolder\subf`. How can I do this?

Comment: Is it the case that you want to delete the entire directory, including all its subdirectories excluding precisely one subdirectory and its contents?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using at least windows vista (`robocopy` command is used), this should do the job

```
@echo off
    setlocal enableextensions disabledelayedexpansion

    rem Create a temporary empty folder
    set "tempFolder=%temp%\%~nx0.%random%%random%%random%.tmp"
    md "%tempFolder%"  >nul 2>nul 

    rem Purge from target folder anything not in the empty source folder, 
    rem but exclude the indicated folder
    robocopy "%tempFolder%" "c:\testfolder" /nocopy /purge /xd "c:\testfolder\subfolder"

    rem Cleanup        
    rmdir "%tempFolder%" /s /q >nul 2>nul
```

Answer (score 0):

If you mean you want to delete all files but not the subfolder you can just use the following

```
cd C:\testfolder
del *.* /S /Q
```

This will delete any files in the "testfolder" and any files in the subfolders but will leave the subfolder there.

Comment: Sorry for the ambiguity, I want to leave the subfolder and its contents intact.

Comment: Try this then http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15547674/exclude-a-folder-inside-temp-when-executing-a-del-batch-file

Comment: I did actually try that before posting my question, but i couldn't get it to work. Either deleted everything or nothing.