# Clean directory, but exclude subdirectory

Tags: svn, batch-file, powershell-4.0

I have directory with subdirectories

```
C:\temp
├───.svn
│   └───gg
├───common
│   ├───.svn
│   │   └───fff
│   └───ggggg
└───todel
    ├───gffgf
    └───jhj
```

I need to clean `c:\temp`, but leave `.svn` folder with it's contents without modification.
The approach described below isn't working for subudirectories (common.svn in my case) 
I would like  to get the following structure as a result

```
C:.
├───.svn
│   └───gg
└───common
    └───.svn
        └───fff
```

[Delete all files and folders but exclude a directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14775672/delete-all-files-and-folders-but-exclude-a-directory) 
Batch approaches overview also didn't give the results as `cmd rd` command is also not unaware of subdirectories during the parent folder deletion.
I've gone through the following:
[Delete all folders except.... (*.BAT)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21048546/delete-all-folders-except-bat) 
[Exclude a folder inside temp when executing a del batch file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15547674/exclude-a-folder-inside-temp-when-executing-a-del-batch-file)

Comment: You can always just move the subfolders to root and then delete temp

Answer (score 2):

It takes surprisingly little code if you use recursive CALLs properly.

Be careful with this script! It can do harm if misused.

The script must not reside within the root hierarchy that is to be "cleaned".

The current directory must not be one of the folders that is to be removed.

As written, the script does not account for Hidden, System, or ReadOnly files or folders.

**PURGE.BAT**

```
@echo off
setlocal disableDelayedExpansion
if /i "%~nx1" equ ".svn" exit /b 1
del /q "%~1.\*"
set "keep=0"
for /d %%F in ("%~1.\*") do call "%~f0" "%%~fF" && rd "%%F" || set "keep=1"
exit /b %keep%
```

**EDIT:** The code has been edited to work properly with all of the following use cases: (Assume the current directory is "c:\test")

```
purge.bat "c:\temp"
purge.bat "c:\temp\"
purge.bat "d:\"
purge.bat "d:"
```

See [How to safely append a file name to a Windows folder path argument?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/26702311/1012053) for more info.

Answer (score 1):

```dos
@echo off
    setlocal enableextensions disabledelayedexpansion

    set "folder=c:\temp"

    rem Temporary files
    set "folderList=%temp%\%~nx0.folder.tmp"
    set "SVNList=%temp%\%~nx0.svn.tmp"
    set "notSVNList=%temp%\%~nx0.notsvn.tmp"

    rem Retrieve the list of all folders
    dir /s /ad /b "%folder%\*" | sort > "%folderList%"

    rem Retrieve the list of svn folders
    findstr /i /r /c:"\\\.svn[\\]" /c:"\\\.svn$" "%folderList%" > "%SVNList%"

    rem Retrieve the list of not svn folders
    findstr /v /i /r /c:"\\\.svn[\\]" /c:"\\\.svn$" "%folderList%" > "%notSVNList%"

    rem For each folder not in svn list
    for /f "usebackq delims=" %%a in ("%notSVNList%") do (
        rem If the folder exist test if it is a parent of a svn folder 
        rem If it is a parent delete its contents else remove the folder
        if exist "%%a" findstr /l /b /c:"%%a\\" "%SVNList%" >nul && ( 
            del /q "%%a\*" 
        ) || ( 
            rd /s /q "%%a" 
        )
    )

    rem Remove remaining files in starting folder
    del /q "%folder%\*" >nul 2>nul 

    rem Remove temporary files
    del /q "%folderList%" >nul 2>nul 
    del /q "%SVNList%" >nul 2>nul 
    del /q "%notSVNList%" >nul 2>nul
```

Answer (score 1):

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

rem Traverse the tree in top-down order and get subdirectories that could be deleted
set tos=0
for /D /R "C:\temp" %%a in (*) do (
   set "subdir=%%a"
   if "!subdir:\.svn=!" equ "%%a" (
      set /A tos+=1
      set "stack[!tos!]=%%a"
   )
)

rem Process subdirectories in opposite (bottom-up) order
for /L %%i in (%tos%,-1,1) do (
   rem Delete all files in the subdirectory
   del /Q "!stack[%%i]!\*.*"
   rem And remove the subdirectory if it becomes empty
   rd "!stack[%%i]!" 2>NUL
)
```

Answer (score 0):

not tested but something like this should work:

```
svn move temp\* .
svn delete temp
```