# How to safely append a file name to a Windows folder path argument?

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

Suppose I have a batch script that expects a folder path in argument `%1`. I want to append a file name to the path and use that in a command. Is there a simple way to do this in a way that is reliable in all situations?

I do not want to `PUSHD %1` and simply ignore the path afterward. Assume my logic requires the current directory to remain unchanged.

The issue is the `%1` argument may or may not have a terminating backslash - i.e. `c:\path` or `c:\path\`.

Typically I can simply use `"%~1\file.ext"` because Windows treats `"c:\path\file.ext"` and `"c:\path\\file.ext"` identically.

But there is one nasty case - `c:\`

The following commands produce this error: `The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect.`

```
dir "c:\\file.ext"
del "c:\\file.ext"
```

The odd thing is, these commands work just fine:

```
if exist "c:\\file.ext" echo OK
echo text>"c:\\file.ext"
copy "c:\\file.ext" "somePath"
xcopy "c:\\file.ext" "somePath"
```

There is another problematic case - `c:`, meaning the current directory on drive C:, will give the wrong result if I append a backslash. `"c:file.ext"` is not the same as `"c:\file.ext"`.

**Is there a simple way to safely append a file name to any given folder path argument?**

I am not concerned with UNC paths, as I do not use them very often, and I believe there are some commands that do not play nice with UNC paths.

*Note: This is a case where I am posting a paired question and answer. This issue has been a thorn in my side for a number of years, and I just recently discovered a simple solution that I thought others may be interested in.*

Answer (score 8):

***EDIT - answer changed to address MC ND's comment***

The solution is so simple :-)  `"%~f1.\file.ext"`

Windows file names cannot end with `.` or `<space>`, so all Windows commands simply ignore trailing `.` and `<space>` in file/folder names.

And a single `.` following a backslash represents the current directory at that location.

Assume the current working directory is `c:\test`, then the table below show how various values get resolved:

```
"%~1"        | "%~f1.\file.ext"       | equivalent to
-------------+------------------------+------------------------
"c:\folder\" | "c:\folder\.\file.ext" | "c:\folder\file.ext"
             |                        |
"c:\folder"  | "c:\folder.\file.ext"  | "c:\folder\file.ext"
             |                        |
"c:\"        | "c:\.\file.ext"        | "c:\file.ext"
             |                        |
"c:"         | "c:\test.\file.ext"    | "c:\test\file.ext"
             |                        |
"."          | "c:\test.\file.ext"    | "c:\test\file.ext"
             |                        |
".."         | "c:\.\file.ext"        | "c:\file.ext"
             |                        |
<no value>   | "c:\test.\file.ext"    | "c:\test\file.ext"  I hadn't thought of this case
                                                            until I saw MC ND's answer
```

You can easily reduce the expression into the canonical equivalent form using a FOR loop:

```
for %%A in ("%~f1.\file.ext") do echo "%%~fA"
```

As Harry Johnston states in his comment, this solution does not work with UNC root paths (`\\server\shareName`) or long paths (`\\?\c:\somePath`). See [MC ND's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26705385/1012053) if you need to support either of those cases. The [Harry Johnston answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26705638/1012053) is simpler, but it does not support the case of no argument given.

Comment: Sorry, you forgot `c:.`, that will be converted to `c:..\file`

Comment: It doesn't work on the root of a share, e.g., `\\server\share.\file.ext` won't work.  Otherwise works fine for UNC paths.  It also won't work for long paths, i.e., starting with \\?\

Comment: @MC ND - Right you are! That is an important case. I believe I fixed the problem by adding the `~f` modifier. Answer has been modified. Thanks!

Comment: @HarryJohnston - Thanks for that info. I'm not concerned with UNC paths or long paths. But I would be interested in seeing a solution that does work for them, if possible.

Answer (score 2):

I don't see a way to make it work for all the cases. Your solution will handle all the local paths cases, but to handle UNC or long paths it seems that it is necessary to first correct the path and then append the file data

```dos
@echo off
    setlocal enableextensions disabledelayedexpansion

    for /f "delims=" %%a in ("%~f1."
    ) do for /f "delims=" %%b in ("%%~fa\file.ext"
    ) do echo "%%~fb"
```

This "should" handle local, network or long paths (the reason for the `for /f` is the `?`), both absolute and relative, and the posibility of no giving a path in the command line.

Comment: +1, That appears to work, but it looks odd, given that `\\?\` paths are not supposed to support `.` or `..` relative path indicators. I like Harry's simpler solution better.

Comment: @dbenham, the reason for the two `for` loops is not to face the relative paths (that, as in your code, are handled by `%~f1`) but to handle the case in where no path is given and the final file reference must point to the current folder.

Comment: Ahh - most excellent. I hadn't even thought to test with no argument. Only one loop is needed to support no supplied path, but two loops as you have it is required to support both no supplied path and UNC shared root. Note, you should add `EOL=:` to handle the unlikely case of a relative path beginning with `;`. There are no valid paths that begin with `:`.

Comment: @dbenham, I think there is no need for the `EOL`. The processed value is `%~f1.`, sure I am missing something, but, how can `%~f1` return a string starting with `;`?

Comment: Oops. You are right of course. There is no need for `EOL=:`

Answer (score 2):

Since ~f eliminates multiple backslashes, I *think* this works just as well as the original proposal, and also appears to handle share roots and long paths correctly:

```
for /F "delims=" %%i in (%~f1\file.ext) do set filename=%%~fi
```

Comment: +1, Not as convenient as my answer, but it looks to be a winner if UNC share root or long path support is required. However, you should add `EOL=:`, in the unlikely case that a path starts with a `;`. There are no valid paths that begin with `:`, so it is a safe EOL character.

Comment: I've decided I like MC ND's answer better, as it supports the case of no supplied argument, meaning current working directory.

Comment: Never mind about `EOL=:`. It is not needed because of `~f`. (Doh!)