# Safely append file name to path into a batch file variable

Tags: batch-file

I'm trying to achieve the same functionality as the existing post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/26702311/1838819) but rather than doing so within a loop, I need to get this to work for setting a variable, while accounting for spaces within the path component, **and** a possible trailing backslash in the path. I've tried a variety of approaches which get me *close* but not quite. My current batch file is;

```shell
@echo off

goto start
:NormalizePath
set "%test%=%1.\%2"
exit /b

:start
SET test=C:\Program Files (x86)\SomeFolder\x64
echo Started with [%test%]
call :NormalizePath %test% "SignTool.exe"
echo Processed [%test%]

:end
```

What I've tried;

- The above produces: `Processed [C:\Program Files (x86)\SomeFolder\x64]`
- Removing quotes from `"SignTool.exe"` results in the same
- Changing the `set` to `set test="%1.\%2"` results in: `Processed ["C:\Program.\Files"]`
- Changing the `set` to `set test="%1"\%2` results in: `Processed ["C:\Program\Files"]`
- Changing the `call` to `call :NormalizePath "%test%" SignTool.exe` results in `Processed [""C:\Program Files (x86)\SomeFolder\x64"\SignTool.exe"]` (note the double quotes)

  - Further changing the `set` to `set test=%1\%2` results in `Processed ["C:\Program Files (x86)\SomeFolder\x64"\SignTool.exe]` which is *correct* but results in `Processed ["C:\Program Files (x86)\SomeFolder\x64\"\SignTool.exe]` if the source path has a trailing `\`.

I've also tried using a different approach using string parsing to check the last character but this doesn't work with spaces;

```shell
if "%TOOL_LOCATION:~-1%"=="\" (
    set TOOL_LOCATION="%TOOL_LOCATION:~0,-1%"
)
SET test=%TOOL_LOCATION%\SignTool.exe
```

I can almost get there while accounting for spaces and a possible trailing backslash in the source path - but no cigar. I feel I'm not quite accounting for path and quote expansion and that's throwing my logic awry.

Comment: You should really define your situation in this question, and include with it, some passed arguments, the method(s) you are using to pass them, and the results you require from each. Then as you haven't used the example suggested in the self answer by the author of that linked question, which doesn't use a loop, explain to us the issue you have with using `%~f1.\%~2`, which it seemingly offers.

Comment: @Compo, all arguments are present in the OP - there's nothing external being passed in. That first label is a sub routine. The `%~f1.\%~2` only works for the `%%f` in a loop - and yes I did try it, though it is not present in the examples above. Indeed, if you try `%~f1`, it will try and extract the file name from the first parameter, and we want the full path.

Comment: `SET test=C:\Program Files (x86)\SomeFolder\x64` should be `SET "test=C:\Program Files (x86)\SomeFolder\x64"`, and `call :NormalizePath %test% "SignTool.exe"` should be `call :NormalizePath "%test%" "SignTool.exe"`.

Comment: BTW, currently `set "%test%=%1.\%2"` is completely the wrong syntax. It would attempt `set "C:\Program Files (x86)\SomeFolder\x64=C:\Program.\Files"`! Try changing it to `Set "test=%~f1.\%~2"`, along with my other suggestions.

Comment: Now explain to us what the problem is with using a loop, or `pushd` with `popd`.

Comment: @Compo, your first few suggestions result in the following output `C:\Program.\Files`. However, as you point out, why not use the `for` example anyway - it's a good one. It doesn't work as is on the other post (it writes out the current folder rather than the one I want to append to), but does with a bit of tweaking. My earlier attempts hadn't worked but with the extra info from yourself and Mofi especially around quote expansion, this has helped - thank you both!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL
echo.

goto start
:NormalizePath
set "test=%~1.\%~2"
set "test=%test:.\=%"
exit /b

:start
SET test=C:\Program Files (x86)\SomeFolder\x64
echo Started with [%test%]
call :NormalizePath "%test%" "SignTool.exe"
echo Processed [%test%]
SET test=C:\Program Files (x86)\SomeFolder\x64\
echo Started with [%test%]
call :NormalizePath "%test%" "SignTool.exe"
echo Processed [%test%]

:end
echo.
GOTO :EOF
```

`set "%test%=` will set a *variable* with the name [the *content* of `test`]

You need to pass *both* parameters in quotes since *each* may contain spaces.

The syntax `%~1` removes the quotes from the parameter.

Then remove `.\` from the string if it exists. Note that this may interfere with the intention if either of the parameters contains `.\`

Comment: What does the `%test:.\=%` do? I've tried googling but it's not great with symbols

Comment: See `set /?` for documentation (or many, many examples on SO). The syntax is `%` `varname` `:` `string1` `=` `string2` `%` where `%` may be `!` if required; `string2` may be empty. Substitute for (case-insensitive) `string1` with `string2`. So in this case, substitute *nothing* for the string `.\`.

Answer (score 0):

I've marked [Magoo](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2128947/magoo)'s post as the correct one as it answers the question using the source structure.

The answer here is to document another solution that derives from [Compo](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6738015/compo)'s and [Mofi](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3074564/mofi)'s comments on the OP, and the original link to the related post ([here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/26702311/1838819), which doesn't work 'as is' in this scenario). Using all of the feedback and info, the following solution *also* works;

```shell
@echo off

SET "test=C:\Program Files (x86)\SomeFolder\x64"
echo Started with [%test%]
for %%A in ("%test%.\SignTool.exe") do set "test=%%~fA"
echo Processed [%test%]
```